# How can we expand all the columns from cosmos Db collection in DataBricks

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I came across one strange issue in cosmos Db collection
There were total 5000 documents in a collection where  a new column was added at last document but when I was trying to read the collection, all columns are not expanding/coming means I could not able to get all column details.

Reason which I found after testing that after 1000 document if we add any new column and if it is not available in previous 1000 document then we will not able to get that column.

For temporary solution, I just added that new column with in 1000 document with any value then I could able to see that new column.

How can I see all columns from collection if any new column is added anywhere at any place in document?

I am using Azure Cosmos DB with MongoDB API.

I am using below command to read mongo db collection

```
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("database","ccdb").option("collection","cardBillOrder").load()
```

Connection details I have added in advance tab of the cluster where I have added below

```
spark.mongodb.output.uri mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxx@xxxx 
spark.mongodb.input.uri mongodb://xxxxxx:xxxxx@xxxxx
```

After reading the collection when I am doing filter on that particular id, then I am getting all updated records which had added but with out newly added attribute.

So when I added that new field through Mongo Db Compass, then after I could able to see that new column.

Comment: show how do you access CosmosDB

Comment: I am using below command to read mongo db collection                                              df = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("database","ccdb").option("collection","cardBillOrder").load()                             Connection details I have added in advance tab of the cluster where I have spark.mongodb.output.uri mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxx@xxxx
spark.mongodb.input.uri mongodb://xxxxxx:xxxxx@xxxxx

Comment: @BIKASH - please *edit your question* to include any relevant code, output, etc. Fairly unreadable as a comment. Also, please edit your question to be specific about what database you're connecting to (a MongoDB instance? Cosmos DB with MongoDB API? Something else?). Have you set up a schema for your dataframe? (again, put that info in your question, not in a comment). FYI there are no "columns" in either MongoDB or Cosmos DB. Just properties within documents.